# What are the defaults for Binding.Mode=Default for WPF controls?

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, dependency-properties, binding-mode

In WPF [`Binding.Mode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx), when selecting [Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingmode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Data_BindingMode_Default), it depends in the property being binded.

I am looking for some list or some convention or any information for the defaults for the various controls.
I mean, what properties are `TwoWay` by default and so on.
Any links, ideas, thoughts and even rants are welcommed!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

> Similar to UpdateSourceTrigger, the
>   default value for the Mode property
>   varies for each property.
>   User-editable properties such as
>   `TextBox.Text`, `ComboBox.Text`,
>   `MenuItem.IsChecked`, etc, have `TwoWay`
>   as their default Mode value. To figure
>   out if the default is `TwoWay`, look at
>   the Dependency Property Information
>   section of the property. If it says
>   `BindsTwoWayByDefault` is set to true,
>   then the default Mode value of the
>   property is `TwoWay`. To do it
>   programmatically, get the property
>   metadata of the property by calling
>   `GetMetadata` and then check the boolean
>   value of the `BindsTwoWayByDefault`
>   property.

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20100209025938/http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx

The safest way would be to always be explicit what kind of binding mode you want from a binding.

Comment: Is there a place where I can find a list of all the properties and their BindingMode defaults? what are the rules?

Comment: The list of properties is endless. I guess http://msdn.microsoft.com lists most of the ones from Microsoft. I don't see any information and the binding mode there so I guess you would have to find that out by yourself. The url that I gave in my answer explains how to find them

Comment: What about dependency properties whose metadata are UIPropertyMetadata rather than FrameworkPropertyMetadata?  The MSDN docs for such properties don't mention BindsTwoWayByDefault since that boolean doesn't exist on UIPropertyMetadata.

Comment: Not a list but the properties that use two-way binding by default have this mentioned in the `Dependency Property Information` segment. There is an `BindsTwoWayByDefault` entry in the `Metadata properties set to true` row.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a way to find the Default mode supported by a DP -

> .NET Reflector is your friend. With reflector, search for `TextBox` and
>   look at the source for the static constructor (`.cctor()`). Here, you
>   will be able to find the code used for registering the `TextProperty`
>   DP:
>
> ```
> TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
>                (
>                    "Text", 
>                    typeof(string), 
>                    typeof(TextBox), 
>                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
>                    (
>                       string.Empty, 
>                       FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal |
>                       FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
>                       new PropertyChangedCallback(TextBox.OnTextPropertyChanged), 
>                       new CoerceValueCallback(TextBox.CoerceText), 
>                       true, 
>                       UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus
>                    )
>                 );
> ```
>
> Notice that a parameter is passed to the Register method indicating
>   the default Binding Mode:
>   `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`. If you use
>   reflector to look at the registration for TextBlock’s Text DP, you
>   will see that no such value is passed, in which case we assume the
>   binding is one way by default.

Taken from Bea Stollnitz's post : [How can I update an explicit binding within a template?](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?m=200705)

Although having some kind of list of important DP's would be very helpful.

Comment: Its also easy to lookup the reference source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/TextBox.cs,47e834d7646f17c6,references

Answer (score 3):

Was looking for a list as well, mostly to find out which bindings could be set to one-way to improve performance. The following functions can help you find which controls use two-way binding by default:

```
public IList<DependencyProperty> GetAttachedProperties(DependencyObject obj)
{
    var result = new List<DependencyProperty>();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj, new Attribute[] { new PropertyFilterAttribute(PropertyFilterOptions.Valid) }))
    {
        var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(pd);
        if (dpd != null)
        {
            result.Add(dpd.DependencyProperty);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public bool IsBindsTwoWayByDefault(DependencyObject obj, DependencyProperty property)
{
    var metadata = property.GetMetadata(obj) as FrameworkPropertyMetadata;
    if (metadata != null)
    {
        return metadata.BindsTwoWayByDefault;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using a print function, gives us a list:

```
var objList = new List<DependencyObject> { new TextBox(), new TextBlock(), new Label(), new ComboBox(), new Button() };
foreach (var obj in objList)
{
    var props = GetAttachedProperties(obj);
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        if(IsBindsTwoWayByDefault(obj, prop))
            Debug.WriteLine($"{obj} : {prop.OwnerType}:{prop.Name}");
    }
}
```

Sample result (control properties with two-way binding as default)

```
System.Windows.Controls.TextBox : System.Windows.Controls.TextBox:Text
System.Windows.Controls.TextBox : System.Windows.Controls.TextSearch:Text
System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock : System.Windows.Controls.TextSearch:Text
System.Windows.Controls.Label : System.Windows.Controls.TextSearch:Text
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:0 : System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox:IsDropDownOpen
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:0 : System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox:Text
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:0 : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector:SelectedIndex
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:0 : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector:SelectedItem
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:0 : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector:SelectedValue
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:0 : System.Windows.Controls.TextSearch:Text
System.Windows.Controls.Button : System.Windows.Controls.TextSearch:Text
```

Interestingly, most controls have a TextSearch property which has two-way binding.